# Isomorphic categories

Tags: category-theory

in our lecture notes there is the Statement that the categories of $K$-vector spaces together with linear endomorphisms is isomorphic to the category of $K[X]$-modules. Now I know how to view a vector space togehter with a linear endomorphism as a $K[X]$-module and vice versa, but I am confused with the category-theoritical point of view. How do I define a functor between these to categories?

My main problem is that I used a vector space AND a linear endomorphism to get a $K[X]$-module, thus mapping from objects and morphisms in the category of vector spaces at the same time...

*An attempt of understanding:* Do I have to consider a pair (vector space, endomorphsm) as an object in the category of vector spaces together with linear endomorphism? What are the morphisms then and how do I map them to $K[X]$-module homomorphisms?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $K [X] $ is the ring of polynomials? If so, could you please explain how you associate $(V,T) $ to a module over the polynomials?

Comment: Take $f(x).v=f(T)(v)$ as the $K[X]$-action on $V$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that you need to consider the objects as not just vector spaces but rather as as a vector space equipped with a distinguished endomorphism.

The natural definition of morphisms in this category will be linear maps that are compatible with the endomorphisms.  That is, given two pairs $(V_1, T_1)$ and $(V_2,T_2)$ of vector spaces with endomorphism, then a morphism $f: (V_1, T_1) \to (V_2, T_2)$ will be a map $f: V_1 \to V_2$ such that $f \circ T_1 = T_2 \circ f$.  When you view $V_1, V_2$ as $K[x]$-modules, this compatibility condition is equivalent to forcing $f$ to be not just linear but a map of $K[X]$-modules.  This allows defining the desired functors on morphisms to be straightforward.